# Are torch.nn.ReLU and torch.nn.Sigmoid trainable?

Tags: python, deep-learning, neural-network, pytorch, gru

I build a simple GRU model with PyTorch. It includes 4 sub-modules.

I noted that some dictionaries return by the `state_dict()` of them are empty after training, while ones of the other sub-modules certainly have some weights and bias.

The code:

```
class GruModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, inputs, nodes, layers=2):
        super(GruModel, self).__init__()
        self.gru_m = nn.GRU(input_size=inputs, num_layers=layers, hidden_size=nodes,
                            batch_first=True, dropout=0.5)
        self.activt_f = nn.ReLU()
        self.output_f = nn.Linear(nodes, 1)
        self.probab_f = nn.Sigmoid()

    def forward(self, x, h):
        o, h = self.gru_m(x, h)
        o = self.activt_f(o[:, -1])
        out = self.output_f(o)
        return self.probab_f(out)

    def trainWith(self, ...):
        ''' training body '''
        criterion = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
        optimizer = torch.optim.Adadelta(self.parameters(), lr=learn_rat)
        lr_schdlr = torch.optim.lr_scheduler.ExponentialLR(
            optimizer, gamma=0.99)
        t_loader = torch_data.DataLoader(...)
        for e in range(epochs):
            for x, p_label, n_label in t_loader:
                optimizer.zero_grad()
                out = self(x, self.init_hidden(batch_size))
                loss = criterion(out, p_label)
                loss.backward()
                optimizer.step()
            lr_schdlr.step()

    def save(self, full_path: str):
        print(self.gru_m.state_dict())
        print(self.activt_f.state_dict())
        print(self.output_f.state_dict())
        print(self.probab_f.state_dict())
```

In real running, the state_dict of the sub-module `self.gru_m` and `self.output_f`
have values as expected, but the ones of the sub-module `self.activt_f` (nn.ReLU) and `self.probab_f` (nn.Sigmoid) have nothing.

Don't care about my training process, I feed it with tons of data and run through hundreds of epochs, and the model can do classification as I expected.

I'm interested in whether the later two modules are trainable, or they  do **NOT** need any weights and bias with them to do their work?

If so, can we say that the `torch.nn.Sigmoid` is same as `torch.nn.functional.sigmoid`? Because they are all dummy functions, not stateful objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two layer modules you are mentioning are activation functions which are not parametrized. This means they are not "trainable" since they don't hold any parameters.

However, `nn` modules are *classes* (they can be stateful) while `nn.functional` utilities are *functions* (they are not stateful).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know that they are classes(instances). In other words, in some situation, they also can be stateful and hold some parameters with them? Just in this prog, they need hold nothing?

Comment: Indeed, [`nn.Sigmoid`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/activation.py#L273) and [`nn.ReLU`](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/activation.py#L67) both don't hold any parameters.